# Removing " \ " from String isn't working for me

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove the slash " \ " from my ArrayList of Strings, however I'm not sure why it's not working for me.

Example of text:

```
{"{\"Type\":\"CALM\",\"Confidence\":57.199989318847656}","{\"Type\":\"HAPPY\",\"Confidence\":38.17924880981445}",
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
for(int i = 0; i < mListUploadedImages.size(); i++){
    String newEmotions = mListUploadedImages.get(i).getEmotions().replaceAll("\\'", "");
    mListUploadedImages.get(i).setEmotions(newEmotions);
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the regular expression for a single backslash character? You can experiment on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @user85421 That fixed it with removing the extra " ' ". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give extra one `'` in "\\'". try with this;

```
String newEmotions = mListUploadedImages.get(i).getEmotions().replace("\\", "");
```